# SPDT mux design

Tags: multiplexer

I am designing an APD preamp and I need to switch between two bias voltages to the APD 25V and 46V.
So I am looking for a SPDT mux that can switch between 25V and 46V in less than 300ns.
For clarification:

- APD is Avalanche Photo Diode.
- Current needed : 30mA max.

Comment: You should explain what an APD is… also your 25-46V signal to be switched: how much current? restriction of impedance or distortion of various kind?

Comment: Why use an SPDT mux? There are more convenient ways as far as I can tell.

Comment: APD is avalanche photo diode. Need 30mA max current.

Comment: Just for understanding: Why do you need to switch within 300ns? Do you need to cycle bias supplies continuously at MHz frequencies?

Comment: can you use a diode for the 25V input and a transistor to switch the 46V

Comment: great idea, @Jasen. I was going to suggest two FETs with inverted drives, but yours is less material.However, it is not going to work if fast turn-off of the 46V is required (depending on the total bias current drawn and APD capacitance). At 10pF and 30mA discharge is only a few ns, but if the bias current is lower or your capacitance is higher you will quickly exceed 300ns. A quick search shows typical capacitances between 1pF and 1nF, so that might well be a concern even at 30mA.

Comment: Andy aka,what is your proposal?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is power multiplexer. There are dedicated ICs for this task, but it might be hard to find one to work at 46 volts (https://www.ti.com/power-management/power-switches/power-muxes/overview.html)

Example of custom power mux circuit that may work with some optimization copied idea from other post ([Switching between two power sources](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/271475/switching-between-two-power-sources)).

[image: Delay 48V to 26V]

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Thanks Ernesto, will try.